# How to skip entries that don't match a pattern when constructing an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm doing some pattern matching on an RDD and would like to select only thoese rows/records matching a pattern. Here is what I currently have,

```
val idPattern = """Id="([^"]*)""".r.unanchored
val typePattern = """PostTypeId="([^"]*)""".r.unanchored 
val datePattern = """CreationDate="([^"]*)""".r.unanchored 
val tagPattern = """Tags="([^"]*)""".r.unanchored 


val projectedPostsAnswers = postsAnswers.map {line => {

      val id = line match {case idPattern(x) => x}
      val typeId = line match {case typePattern(x) => x}
      val date = line match {case datePattern(x) => x}
      val tags = line match {case tagPattern(x) => x}

      Post(Some(id),Some(typeId),Some(date),Some(tags))
  }
}   

case class Post(Id: Option[String], Type: Option[String], CreationDate: Option[String], Tags: Option[String])
```

I'm only interested in row/record which match to all patterns (that is, records that have all those four fields). How can I skip those rows/records not satisfy my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RDD.collect(scala.PartialFunction f)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#collect(scala.PartialFunction,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) to do the filtering and mapping in one step.

For example, if you know the order of these fields in your input, you can merge the regular expressions into one and use a single case:

```
val pattern = """Id="([^"]*).*PostTypeId="([^"]*).*CreationDate="([^"]*).*Tags="([^"]*)""".r.unanchored

val projectedPostsAnswers = postsAnswers.collect {
  case pattern(id, typeId, date, tags) => Post(Some(id), Some(typeId), Some(date), Some(tags))
}
```

The returned `RDD[Post]` will only contain records for which this case matched. Notice that this `collect(PartialFunction)` has nothing to do with `collect()` - it does *not* collect entire data set into driver memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter API.

```
val projectedPostAnswers = postsAnswers.filter(line => f(line)).map{....
```

Create a function 'f' that does your data cleansing for you.  Make sure the function returns true or false, as thats what filter uses to decide whether or not to pass the record.